# Check if <div> has been asynchronously loaded with data-url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a JSP with the following `<div>`:

```
<div class="articleInfo" data-url="${article.url}/infoSheet"></div>
```

If there is any data available for the article, then it will be populated inside the `<div>` like this:

```
<div class="articleInfo" data-url="${article.url}/infoSheet">
     <div class="data">This is data</div>
</div>
```

If no data is available then the `<div>` is left as is.

I tried to do a check with jQuery if the "articleInfo" div has any children, but it doesn't, even if I put the check in the end of `$(document).ready(function () {}` of the last javascript file loaded. I suppose this is due to how the data is loaded with the `data-url` attribute of the `<div>`.

How can I check if any data has been populated?

Comment: How and when you load that content ?

Comment: I'm not a JSP guy but what is loading this content asynchronously??? I guess, this has nothing to do with JSP but client side script (ajax?!)

Comment: you need to do it in the callback function of the ajax request (I'm guessing jsp uses ajax on the data-url)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) like

```
$(function(){
    // assuming there is single element having class articleInfo
    alert($('.articleInfo').is(':empty'));
});
```

And if your `articleInfo` div is filled asynchronously then you need to check its data in your ajax callback like,

```
$.ajax({
   url:....
   data:...
   success:function(data){
       if(!data){
          // this div url has no data
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: This would be fired way before any ajax request completes. As a side note, i didn't downvoted it though

Comment: Yes I was updating my answer for Async call.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i suppose You have no callback for this ajax downloading staff, and this operation not leave any signs of doing ajax like data attributes. If so - no callbacks and signs in DOM then my proposition is to do **setInterval** and in there check divs has data or not:

```
var checkedCount=0;
var maxCheckCount=5;//we check 5 times
var checkInterval=setInterval(function(){

  var $divs=$('div[data-url]');

   $divs.each(function(index){

       if ( $(this).find("div.data") ){

           //our div has data
       }else{

           //our div has no data ( maybe will be downloaded? )

       }
   });

   checkedCount++;

   if (checkedCount==maxCheckCount)
   clearInterval(checkInterval);

},1000); //check every 1 sec
```

So we check 5 times, one on 1 second ( customise it to Your needs). This is not perfect solution, if ajax will be long, then it will stop working before ajax end.

**You can also watch changes in DOM:**

```
$('div[data-url]').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {

     if ($(this).find("div.data")){

         //div has data
     }else{

        //div has no data but in this situation this never calls
     }


});
```